# Different ways to express the fundamentalness of a problem

Tags: sentence-choice

Consider we intend to say that a problem cannot be solved only if we look through more fundamental concepts of a theory.

I suggest these:

> Problem A cannot be solved without resorting to the fundamental concepts of theory B.
>
> Problem A can only be solved at deeper levels of theory B.

Which sentence works well? what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

First off, in your opening statement 'only' ought be 'unless', I am guessing, or 'cannot' ought to be 'can'.

Second, the former variant ("without resorting") sounds a bit like panic.  To "resort" suggests a need to escape, to grasp at something.  That is why I think that the latter variant is more acceptable.